# Cumulative array

Tags: php, math

I have this array:

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12);
```

Is there a function to convert this to:

```
$b = array(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2);
```

So basicaly:

```
$b = array ($a[1]-$a[0], $a[2]-$a[1], $a[3]-$a[2], ... ,$a[n]-$a[n-1]);
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$a = $c = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12);
array_shift($c);
$d = array();
foreach ($a as $key => $value){
   $d[$key] = $c[$key]-$value;
}
array_pop($d);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built-in function that can do this for you, but you could turn your code into one instead. Also, rather than making a second array, `$c`, you could use a regular `for` loop  to loop through the values:

```
function cumulate($array = array()) {
    // re-index the array for guaranteed-success with the for-loop
    $array = array_values($array);

    $cumulated = array();
    $count = count($array);
    if ($count == 1) {
        // there is only a single element in the array; no need to loop through it
        return $array;
    } else {
        // iterate through each element (starting with the second) and subtract
        // the prior-element's value from the current
        for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $cumulated[] = $array[$i] - $array[$i - 1];
        }
    }
    return $cumulated;
}
```

Comment: You should insert `$array = array_values($array);` to reindex the array and avoid any errors due to inconsistent array keys (e.g. when an element was deleted)

Comment: let me explain: if an array `$array = [0 => 1, 1=>2, 3 =>3];` was fed to your function it would fail due to non existent index `2`. Also - count variable should get a `$count--;` as it holds a value that is bigger then the biggest index in the array

Comment: @karka91 I accept; I've updated my answer to include the re-index for full support in the `for` loop. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: @karka91 The `$count` variable is fine; I'm using `< $count`, and I start my loop at `1`, not `0` (and subtract from the *previous* element, not the next); If it were the other way around, or if I used `<= $count`, then I'd need to subtract 1.

Comment: my bad. No need for that one.

Answer (score 1):

I think php has not a build in function for this. There are many ways to solve this, but you already wrote the answer:

```
$len = count($a);
$b = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $len - 1; $i++) {
  $b[] = $a[$i+1] - $a[$i];
}
```